# i cannot open external url in webview in ionic android app

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, webview, ionic-framework

I have this ionic app that opens up an external url in a webview. I have been testing on the ios simulator and it works fine, now testing on android simulator but it does not work. and the android monitor gives me the following error debug message.

```
08-11 19:28:52.229: D/cr_Ime(2813): [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:56] isActive: true
08-11 19:28:52.229: D/cr_Ime(2813): [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:65] hideSoftInputFromWindow
```

and the following error message

```
08-11 19:28:52.070: E/chromium(2813): [ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(2109)] [.CommandBufferContext.RenderWorker-0xf43e1700]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : GLES2DecoderImpl::DoBindTexImage2DCHROMIUM: <- error from previous GL command
08-11 19:28:52.096: E/chromium(2813): [ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(2109)] [.CommandBufferContext.RenderWorker-0xf43e1700]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : GLES2DecoderImpl::DoBindTexImage2DCHROMIUM: <- error from previous GL command
08-11 19:28:52.122: E/chromium(2813): [ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(2109)] [.CommandBufferContext.RenderWorker-0xf43e1700]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : GLES2DecoderImpl::DoBindTexImage2DCHROMIUM: <- error from previous GL command
08-11 19:28:52.226: E/chromium(2813): [ERROR:xwalk_autofill_client.cc(121)] Not implemented reached in virtual void xwalk::XWalkAutofillClient::OnFirstUserGestureObserved()
```

i'm at a complete loss as to what the issue is.

```
function createCORSRequest(method,url)
{
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  if ("withCredentials" in xhr)
  {
    xhr.open(method, url, true);
  }
  else if (typeof XDomainRequest !== "undefined")
  {
    xhr = new XDomainRequest();
    xhr.open(method, url);
  }
  else
  {
    xhr.open(method, url);
  }
  return xhr;
}

var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('portal[username]',name);
formData.append('portal[password]',password);
formData.append('portal[From]','web');

var url = endPoint+ '/login';
var xhr = createCORSRequest('POST', url);

xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
{
  if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200)
  {
    var  jsonObj =   JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    var  status  =   jsonObj.status;
    var  message =   jsonObj.message;

    if(status==='success')
    {
      var token = jsonObj.token;
      home = 'http://127.0.0.1:8888/map/index?token='+token;
      var ref = window.open(home,'_self');
      ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event)
      {
        if (event.url == "http://127.0.0.1:8888/map/logout")
        {
          ref.close();
        }
      });
    }
    else
    {
      alert(message);
    }
  }
};

xhr.send(formData);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to open an url with the [$cordovaInAppBrowser](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/inAppBrowser/) plugin.

```
$cordovaInAppBrowser.open('http://example.com', '_system');
```

I believe you'll have to grant permission to the external url as well in your config.xml

```
<allow-navigation href="http://example.com/*"/>
```

Comment: Can you show the snippet where you're doing all of this? Also is the plugin properly installed in your /plugins folder? Have you been able to test it in an actual android device?

Comment: @radzy i've added the snippet. Well, it works on ios so i'm not sure what the issue is for android and the plugin. I get the same error even on an android device

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand, I don't see the $cordovaInAppBrowser plugin being used, rather you are using the window object (which might work on your browser but not on devices). Also anytime a cordova plugin is used it should be done after the $ionicPlatform.ready event is done, e.g: `$ionicPlatform.ready(function () { $cordovaInAppBrowser('http://example.com', '_system'); }`

Comment: @radzy , $cordovaInAppBrowser.open(home, '_blank', 'location=no,toolbar=no'); that is one of the codes i have tried and even this doesn't work for me

Comment: Is it being called after $ionicPlatform.ready has been fired?

Comment: it should be. its being called in my controller which i assume is called after ionic.platformready

Comment: Nop, you have to call $ionicPlatform.ready inside your controller.